# How to remove mandatory field from the magento Quick Contact feedback extension

Tags: magento

In my magento site i have installed [Quick contact feedback extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/freequickcontact-mageworld.html). Now i need to customize the feedback form fields.How to remove the required field validation from this extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hello check controller file app/code/community/HM/QuickContact/controllers/indexController.php 
comment those you want something like this

```
/*
                if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['name']) , 'NotEmpty')) {
                    echo '<div class="error-msg">'.Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Please fill in required fields.').'</div>';
                    exit; 
                }

                if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['comment']) , 'NotEmpty')) {
                    echo '<div class="error-msg">'.Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Please fill in required fields.').'</div>';
                    exit; 
                }

                if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['email']), 'EmailAddress')) {
                    echo '<div class="error-msg">'.Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Please enter a valid email address. For example johndoe@domain.com.').'</div>';
                    exit; 
                }*/
```

Comment: How to remove the entire validation for success and error and prevent the empty form submission in this extension.